# How tlmgr understands what dependencies to install?

Tags: tlmgr

I created a new package and uploaded it to CTAN.org. Then, I install it with `tlmgr install` and it works and installs only my package. However, when I install, for example, `beamer`, all its dependencies get installed too. In my case, no dependencies are installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To declare dependencies to a package you can, as Joseph said, mail the TeX Live maintainers and they will sort it out accordingly.  Recently (mid-2020 or so), a new way of declaring dependencies was introduced:  you upload, along with your package, a file called (exactly) `DEPENDS.txt` that will live in the top-level directory of your package, along with the `README`.

There are two types of dependencies you can declare: `hard` and `soft`.  `hard` is when your package always needs the dependency, and `soft` is when the dependency is conditional somehow.  For example, the `DEPENDS.txt` file from a package for math typesetting could look like:

```
hard amsfonts
soft unicode-math
```

when `amsfonts` is always needed and `unicode-math` only when using XeTeX or LuaTeX.

You can find the full specification of the `DEPENDS.txt` file in https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html#deps.

---

Note that the package name is the *CTAN* package name, which may differ from the package that you load with `\usepackage`.  For example, in a package I wrote I have `DEPENDS.txt`:

```
hard l3kernel
```

because the package does `\usepackage{expl3}`.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that TeX Live only cares about the hard deps!

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing anything wrong. Dependencies are listed in the TeX Live configuration files based on manual addition of the data - nothing is automatic. You are best emailing the TeX Live list with details of *required* dependencies and Karl et al. will likely add them.

Comment: there is some file one can add to a package  to describe dependencies, but I have forgotten the syntax and the name ;-(

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed - seems easier to just 'mail Karl'

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's a file called `DEPENDS.txt` with lines `hard <dependency>` or `soft <dependency>` (for example I have `hard l3kernel` in a package that requires `expl3`).  Here's the documentation: https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html#deps

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik please, make it an answer, and I'll accept it